# Image Size in Windows 8 File Picker

Tags: windows, windows-8

How to know the size of the picked image , or how to put a limit for the picked image , like Maximum size for Image is 1 MB , Here is my code

```
   var openPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
        openPicker.ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".Jpeg");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".Jpg");

        StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to restrict the size of the picked file in advance.

After the file has been picked, you can call http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.getbasicpropertiesasync.aspx to get its size.